# can we have nested ? : operator in C language. explain if yes, then how

Tags: c

I am learning to code in C language with my friend and my friend asks me Can we have nested ?: operator in C language?  If yes, please send an easy describing it too.

Comment: Why did 'your friend' not just try it?

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I don't think anyone would be so great that he would reply me with so much kindness.

Answer (score 1):

by nested ?: code do you mean this?if  yes then you can write like this..but don't use this in real life as it is messy..
use a simple if  else in stead

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(){

 int a=7;
 int b=6;
 int c=5;
 int d=a>b?(b>c?3:4):1;
 printf("%d",d);
 return 0;
 }
//prints 3
```

Comment: Thanks, actually we just want to know would it work.

Comment: you are welcome